# Insert list of tuple in Saltstack

Tags: python, salt-stack

I'm trying to pass a Python list of tuples ( ex : `[(1, '1€'), (5, '5€')]` ) in my init.sls
It's a config file for my Django web server, and the config at some point need to retrieve this list of tuple from this file.

I tried the followings :

```
amount_choices: [(1, '1€'), (5, '5€')]

amount_choices:
- !!python/tuple : [1, '1€']

amount_choices: {% set amount_choice = (1, '1€') %}
```

None of them worked as intended, at best the value is None whith the last proposition.

How can I insert my list of tuples into a sls file that uses the Jinja2 templates ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back here to post the solution :

in init.sls :

```
amount_choices:
  "5 euros": 5
  "10 euros": 10
  "25 euros": 25
  "Montant libre": 0
```

in the settings_local.py built by saltstack :

```
AMOUNT_CHOICES = [
    {% for key, value in amount_choices.items() -%}
    ( {{ value }}, "{{ key }}" ),
    {% endfor -%}
    ]
```

By constructing a dict and artificially recreating a tuple, we managed to get our way.
Maybe better solutions are available, but I'm leaving this if anyone has the same problem someday.